# Custom implicit module dependency in WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly-11

There's the 3rd-party application `bpm.ear` that contains the ancient `commons-net.jar` in its `/bpm.war/WEB-INF/lib/`.

I need to globally override it with my own version of the jar without patching the files inside the deployment. That is, make this change survive undeployment of the app.

Formerly, when we were using JBoss 4x this was solved by setting the `$CLASSPATH` env. var before starting the server. Of course, this doesn't work in Wildfly 11.

I want to create a custom module inside `${JBOSS_HOME}/modules` (already done) and to create a simple rule to implicitly add this module to *all* apps deployed on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/16.0/subsystem/ee/#attr-global-modules to define a list of modules that should be made available to all deployments.